# Can Kobuki_soft be used for control real turtlebots?

Tags: ros, rocon, kobuki, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Kobuki_soft](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_soft) has two parts: Kobuk_softapps and kobuki_softnode.  Is this pakage only used for simulation of Kokuki in gazebo? or can it be used for controlling real Kobuki robots?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152606/can-kobuki_soft-be-used-for-control-real-turtlebots?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. They are designed to work as simulation since kobuki itself does not have any 3d sensor and computation power.

If you want to try out the real robot, you might want to checkout rapps in  turtlebot_apps instead. such as turtlebot_navigation and map_nav in turtlebot_core_apps. They are not identical but provide similar functionality.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0